# How to add my iPhone web app to apple.com/webapps

Tags: iphone, web-applications

I have created a webapp which is for iPhone. I need 2 helps.

App URL: http://classictutorials.com/ts/

1. How do i submit it to http://www.apple.com/webapps/ ?
2. Whats the best way to share with people who would be using it. Its a free app and neither am asking for any donation. So don't want to share across using money.

Comment: Why is your app url limited to iOS5?

Comment: Because calling various settings from web is limited to IOS5 i guess. I read some where that its part of IOS5. I don't have a lower OS device to test also.

Comment: Oh right OK. I don't think apple maintain that list but if they did, I wouldn't be sure if a limited iOS version web app would make it on!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple adds the webapps on its own, and it didnt add anything to that list after 12/03/2010. So that is a stale list.

If you dont want to spend anything, you may want to advertise it on some forums, where they discuss about the problem your app could solve. Other than that you could try telling people, writing blogs about it or do a link exchange with other apps.

Comment: I'm surprised they still have it online. Maybe iOS web apps really are that significant to them.